# Android studio build failed exception while build with different emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio

> Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
>   Unable to delete directory: /media/user/7EA01F5FA01F1CE9/GitWorkSpace/Myapplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/animated-vector-drawable/23.3.0/jars
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --debug option to get more log output.

How to fix this issue in android studio? Whenever i'm trying to take build in different emulator i have to delete manually build folder inside the app then only i can successfully build the application.

How to fix this issue permanently?

Comment: Try running with `--stacktrace` or `--debug` to get more output and reason about the error

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, my android studio version 2.0 and OS Ubuntu. So, far I didn't found any permanent solution and this problem is current IDE version. You can also check details from here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=206219

So, you can use lower IDE version temporarily (I know this is not a good solution)